# How do i count the number of specific letters in an array, Perl?

Tags: arrays, perl, count

I have an array which only has letters in it, no digits. I want to count the number of times a specific letter shows. I don't want to use a hash, i need to preserve the order of the list.

```
use strict;
use warnings;

my %counts;
$counts{$_}++ for @array;
print "$counts\n";
```

Comment: Please show sample input and the expected output.

Comment: What's not clear is whether a string in the array like "aaa" should count as 1 or 3.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [grep](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/grep.html) for to do it

```
my @ar = qw(abc cde fgh 123 abc);
my $count = grep{ /ab/} @ar;
print $count;
```

Or else use foreach

```
my @ar = qw(abc cde fgh 123 abc);
my $m;
$m+= /ab/,foreach (@ar);
print $m;
```

While the match was encountered `$m` will increment.

Answer (score 2):

The code that you have seems to work find for counting the occurrences. The only problem you have is in displaying the counts. You're using a new scalar variable called `$counts` which is undeclared and empty.

What you want is this:

```
use strict;
use warnings;

my %counts;
$counts{$_}++ for @array;
print "$_: $counts{$_}\n" for keys %counts;
```

Answer (score 1):

You might consider  [Text::CountString](http://search.cpan.org/~bayashi/Text-CountString-0.03/lib/Text/CountString.pm) module on CPAN.